# Assign from array to list of strings in Java

Tags: java, arrays

Is there a way to get rid of `buf`?

```
public Option(String opt) {
    String[] buf;
    buf = opt.split("=");
    key = buf[0];
    value = buf[1];
}
```

I thought of something like `{ key, val } = opt.split("=");` as it would be possible in Perl, IIRC.

Comment: No. Your priorities seem off. Java is not a code-golfing language.

Comment: Why not just `key = opt.split("=")[0];`? The only problem would be performance. Why exactly don't you want `buf`?

Comment: @Arc676 Because he then has `buf[1]` later down.

Comment: @Gendarme Exactly. That's what I meant by performance issue: calling `opt.split` twice. My bad, I should have specified.

Comment: I just wondered if there is a nicer way to do this. There sometimes are cool shortcuts in Java I didn't know about, and I wondered if there is one for this. No offense, @Gendarme.

Comment: A nicer way to do this would be to pass the parts into the constructor already split. Sure, you still have to split it to call the ctor, you just don't have the tight binding to a particular format for `opt` here.

Answer (score 0):

There is `java.util.Scanner`, which gives back one token at a time.  But  it's  a lot harder to use than `split`, and in my experience not worth the trouble for problems simple enough to handle w/ `split`.